# How to make animation when clicking a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to animate a TextView to act like a Button when long pressed?

I've created a TextView using this code

```
<TextView
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"

    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

but even setting `android:longClickable="true"` the TextView does not show the bubble animation when is long pressed. The expected result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXYBO.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set selectable background:

```
<TextView
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    .../>
```

But seeing that you already use `android:background` you can also use `android:foreground` instead of it:

```
<TextView
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    .../>
```

But beware that `android:foreground` will work only starting with API 21 (Lollipop).

If you need to have your `@drawable/rectangle` AND to support Android <5.x then you'll have to create a custom drawable for this to work. See the [RippleDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html) documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks, readers note that you MUST include clickable and focusable true, also!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for ripple effect in listview. please add 
          android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground". in your textview

Comment: george_louis can you pls let us know whether you resolved it

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set your custom background you can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/state_one"></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/state_two"></item>
    <transition
        android:fromId="@+id/usual"
        android:toId="@+id/selected" >
        <animation-list>
            <!--fill in your animation here-->
        </animation-list>
    </transition>
</selector>
```

You have to use the xml above instead `android:background="@drawable/rectangle"`.
Also you need to design `state_one` and `state_two` in your `drawables`.